# cloud messaging and android

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement google cloud messaging and push notifications on my android app

I am following official google tutorial , I am using android studio

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

and I am getting this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException:     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

here is my build.gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
   packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
}
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp.example"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
    jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
 }

}


dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
 compile 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0'
 compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
 compile 'rongi.rotate-layout:rotate-layout:1.0.1'
 compile 'com.vdurmont:emoji-java:2.0.1'
 compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.5'
 compile 'com.github.javadev:underscore:1.6'
 compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
 compile 'org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.2.0'
 compile 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:1.1.1'
 compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
 compile 'com.reginald.swiperefresh:library:1.1.1'
 compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.0'
 compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
 compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.4@aar'
 compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
 compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
 compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
 compile 'in.srain.cube:grid-view-with-header-footer:1.0.12'
 compile 'com.vstechlab.easyfonts:easyfonts:1.0.0'

}
```

also here is my project build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

 buildscript {
   repositories {
     jcenter()
   }
   dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3'
      // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
     // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
     jcenter()
 }
}
```

Comment: I had similar issue. I changed project build.gradle google services version    to     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0'  and it worked

Comment: it didn't work ,can you post your gradle.build file

Answer (score 4):

After some-days and nightmares, Finally I can defeat the problem and believe it could be of help to others.

Because of my massive coded project, test and checking each advice takes about 5 minutes of my system to build. I examined almost all of SO community suggestions and I wanna conclude them here:

This is **most likely** a problem with the dependencies you have listed in your `build.gradle` file for you app.

Things I do not recommend:

> Unless you have an absolute **need** to enable multiDex in your
>   build.gradle **DO NOT DO IT**, this is just stepping over the
>   underlying problem in your app and not getting to the root of it. You
>   are also unnecessarily increasing the size of your apk, and there
>   could be unexpected crashes when there is a conflicting method in your
>   dex file.

Things to look out for:

> Check all your dependencies in your build.gradle file if you have any
>   duplication. Are you referencing a dependency that also includes a
>   dependency you have already included? For example, if your including
>   appcompat-v7 there is no need to include appcompat-v4 since v7
>   includes all features from v4.

My Issue: **GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES** >> causing my app to exceed method limit in my dex file.

If you do not need all the google play services library dependencies DO NOT INCLUDE this line in your build.gradle `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'` and instead just use what you need!! also check if your can build correctly with lower versions of the dependency.

Google has a comprehensive list of the libraries for selectively compiling [**here**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

With all that said you probably only need to include this one line in gradle for your Google Analytics:

```
  dependencies{
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0'
  }
```

Well Done!

Comment: Nice answer. Single dex file can hold only 65,536 methods including every android framework methods, google play service methods etc. [This description](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/tools/building/multidex.html) would be help.

Answer (score 3):

take a look in your gradle console and check the exact error

i just had the same problem. i solved it with:

1. Clean the project (at first, gradle had a error because of multiple classes included)
2. only include the service you really needed from play.
   https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split

Answer (score 2):

```
Add one more file in your dependency list 
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

and add following to your defaultconfig 
 defaultConfig {
//your stuff
        multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: adding multidexenabled can solve the problem but it makes the building time so long also it has a lot of drawbacks

Comment: @Remon either reduce the number of libraries used or use multi-dexing, no other choice

Comment: Not anymore, with the gradle build and subsequent build times are in 2-5 seconds if you are using device fore debug, also the actual performance of app is pretty good. The other alternative you have is to use proguard.You can mask the classes which you don't need. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html